# Нейросеть изменение весов по формуле w^ = w + f^(v3) * E3 * V2

Tags: c++, математика, матрицы

Я делаю нейросеть, мне нужно применить формулу `w^ = w + f^(v3) * E3 * V2` для обновление весов методом `backpropagation` в виде матриц, где:

1. w^ - это новые веса
2. w - старые веса
3. f^(v3) - производная функции активации в точке значения нейрона 3 слоя
4. E3 - значение ошибки 3 слоя
5. v2 значение нейрона 2 слоя

Когда я умножаю `F^(v3) * E3` у меня есть массив из `10` элементов производных в точках выходных данных из 3 слоя которые я могу представить в виде матрицы- вектора из (столбцы = 1 , строки = 10 ) так как `e3` у меня тоже массив из `10` элементов который я так же конвертирую в матрицу-вектор и транспонирую ее и получается матрица размера `(10,1)` в результате умножения получиться матрица `(1,1)` или если первая матрица будет `(10,1)`, а вторая `(1,10)` то получиться матрица `(10,10)`.

И если этот результат умножить дальше на `v2` значение 2 слоя в нем `88` нейронов матрица будет `(1,88)` на вариант `(10,10)` не умножиться остается `(1,1)` и будет в итоге при умножении `(1,88)`. Я не могу этот результат сложить "+" с `w` матрицей весов которая размерами `(88,10)` или `(10,88)`. Возможно это я не правильно формулу понял или не правильно умножаю или что- то еще не правильно делаю?

Вот как в коде я это пытался реализовать:

```
for (int i = l - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    matrix e(layers[i], 1); matrix n(1, layers[i]);
    double* pro_ner = new double[layers[i]];
    for (int h = 0; h < layers[i]; h++) {
        pro_ner[h] = nerons[i][h] * (1 - nerons[i][h]);
    }
    e.arrtomatrix(err[i]); n.arrtomatrix(pro_ner);
    matrix n2(1, layers[i - 1]); n2.arrtomatrix(nerons[i - 1]);
    matrix t = e * n;
    matrix t2 = е * n2;
    matrix w(layers[i], layers[i - 1]);
    w.arrtomatrix(weights[i - 1]);
    cout << endl << endl;;
    w = w + t;
    weights[i - 1] = w.matrixtoarray();
}
```

где `l` это количество слоев массива `layers ={28*28,88,10}`.

```
int* layers;
double** weights;
double** nerons;
double** err;
int l = 3;
```

я формулу взял с видео на ютубе и она могла быть не правильная , автор мог сделать опечатку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например у вас есть матрица весов между вторым и третьим слоем размерностью `[4, 3]` (4 нейрона во втором слою и 3 нейрона в третьем), так же у вас имеется:

1. Вектор `f'(V)` - вектор значений производной функции активации 3 слоя получается `длина = 3`,
2. `e3` - вектор ошибок нейронов третьего слоя, то есть `длина = 3`
3. `v2` - вектор выходных значений нейронов второго слоя, `длина = 4`

В уравнении `w' = w + ...` мы должны сложить матрицу размерностью `[4, 3]` с матрицей такой же размерности.

То есть результатом `f'(v) * e3 * v2 * 0.2` должна быть матрицы размерностью `[4, 3]`.

Для начала пусть `x` - вектор в нашем случае длинной 3, где `x[i] = f'(v)[i] * e3[i]`. То есть вектор `x` это результат поэлементного умножения вектора `f'(v)` и `e3`.

После чего, приводим вектор `x` к матрице размерностью `[1, 3]` (Можно сразу в какой нибудь функции поэлементного умножения векторов приводить результирующий вектор к матрице, чтобы меньше времени тратить), а так же вектор `v2` к матрице размерностью `[4, 1]`.

Далее просто перемножаем эти матрицы и складываем с матрицей `w`.

```
x[1, 3] = { {f'(v)[0] * e3[0], f'(v)[1] * e3[1], f'(v)[2] * e3[2]} }
v2[4, 1] = { {v2[0]}, {v2[1]}, {v2[2]}, {v2[3]} }

v2 * x = { { v2[0, 0] * x[0, 0], v2[0, 0] * x[0, 1], v2[0, 0] * x[0, 2] },
           { v2[1, 0] * x[0, 0], v2[1, 0] * x[0, 1], v2[1, 0] * x[0, 2] },
           { v2[2, 0] * x[0, 0], v2[2, 0] * x[0, 1], v2[2, 0] * x[0, 2] },
           { v2[3, 0] * x[0, 0], v2[3, 0] * x[0, 1], v2[3, 0] * x[0, 2] }}
```

Можно заметить, что например первая строка `(v2 * x)[0]` это результат посимвольного перемножения `v2[0] * x`, то есть функция, которую мы сделали для получения вектора `x` может пригодится и тут для расчета. А вообще т.к. `v2` это матрица с 1 столбиком, то по факту `(v2 * x)[0] = v2[0][0] * x`, то есть умножение вектора на число.

Comment: e3 это значение ошибок в 3 слое то есть дина 3

Comment: @vlad предыдущая версия ответа была моим бредом, я отредактировал ответ

Comment: должно сработать , спасибо